# Change profile of all running Gnome Terminals on the fly over command line

Tags: gnome-terminal

Currently I'm working on a script which changes my gnome terminal theme depending on daytime.
I do this with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default "$terminal_profile_id"
```

It is working well, but the new color theme is only visible when I start new terminal sessions.
I'm looking for a way to also change the profile of all already running gnome terminals.
It is possible via the terminal gui, but is there also a way to do it over command line?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669720/53656.